# Batch importing google drive hyperlinks to Microsoft Access

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, ms-access-2007

Before I begin: I am not a data scientist by training. I am a historian/archivist/digital humanist but — and I really need to emphasize — my background is more humanities oriented. I can cobble together an SQL expression, and am beginner/intermediate with Excel.

I’ve been assigned a project to construct a membership database for a partner organization. I’m using Microsoft Access, because they told me to, and that’s not going to change. Basically we are merging two membership tables (which I have successfully done) and then adding a new field, which is a link to the membership application for each member. Some members have more than one record, extra records are referred to as supplementals.

There are about 10,000 applications, stored as PDFs. They are all (21GB~) being stored on our partners google drive. So I’m taking the google drive link, and putting it in the hyperlink field “application.” Supplementals get their own field.

The unique ID for each file name is in the middle of the file name (naming convention: last, first_#ID_sX where the s is added if it is a supplemental app and X represents which supplemental app it is [some members have up to 12])

My question: is there a way to batch import these links? Am I doomed to individually copy/paste these applications 10,000 times because Microsoft Access isn’t supported by Sharepoint, so I can’t even get others to help me?

I’m thinking maybe there’s a way to batch import the links to a spreadsheet version of the table and then import the whole thing to access, replacing the original.

If you have any suggestions could you please explain in the simplest terms. Thanks.

I don’t even know where to begin— I’ve been individually linking files. It’s tedious.

Comment: There are many ways to solve your problem. I would simply write a program to list Google Drive files. Search for articles like this one: https://spreadsheet.dev/export-list-of-files-in-google-drive-to-google-sheets-using-apps-script